# How do I make SWT Composite scroll with content inside it

Tags: java, eclipse, shell, swt, composite

I have a class that creates a Shell and grabs announcements from a website using an API and lists them on the window. How do I make it so that the content inside of the composite scrolls?

Application window: https://c.theartex.net/loZntC2f9y/

API used: https://c.theartex.net/19hzUAMW0n/

Comment: I guess you are looking for the ScrolledComposite: http://www.codeaffine.com/2016/03/01/swt-scrolledcomposite/

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann i tried that but it wasn't working, i'll try it agian.

Comment: @AllenLantz Could you share a [mcve] of what you've tried with the `ScrolledComposite`?